# Integrate Stripe in React

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I would like to know whether it is possible to integrate the same design(checkout form) i.e,(https://checkout.stripe.dev/preview) in ReactJs. I have used the doc but able to add card number, expiry and cvv but unable add remaining fields.

PS: package used: npm i @stripe/react-stripe-js, npm i @stripe/stripe-js

Answer (score 0):

You can get build a Checkout form that looks very close in React by using the [PaymentElement](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element). You can follow [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart) (selecting Web as the platform and React as the frontend) to get started.